# Embedding form flow bot in custom client

Tags: c#, botframework

I have created a form flow bot using the Azure portal in C#. I want to embed this bot into my custom client which will be a MVC application. I have already set a Direct Line Connection and have both secret keys with me.

Is there any working sample available for this?

I don't want to embed iframe. I want to embed the bot functionality into my custom chat window.

Comment: "I don't want the to embed iframe. I want to embed the bot functionality into my custom chat window." - what for? Why is the webchat provided by Microsoft not acceptable for you?

Comment: @rudolf_franek I need to add custom styling into my chat window that's why I am looking for this?

Comment: And have you tried ever? https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS

Comment: @rudolf_franek I haven't found any working sample for DirectLineJS.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things here. For reference the [Webchat repo can be found here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat)

1. The webchat control is an open source project that will allow you to customize it as you see fit.  This would allow you to include custom styling as you mentioned is your main concern.
2. Webchat itself is an example of DirectlineJS
3. In the [DirectlineJS repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS) readme there are examples of how to use it in a simple walkthrough.  Is there something you would like to do that isn't covered?